# Automate workflow using apex

Tags: email, workflow

My project requires a large number of notifications to be sent and workflow is reaching limit. Is there any way I could automate the workflow using apex? For example by using object 'workflow' and 'workflow actions'.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are dealing with large numbers, then workflow is not the right choice. You should use `batch apex` to handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks @Abbas, But how do I capture if record satisfies all evaluation criteria? Should I manually give the check for all the conditions?

Comment: Yes @alvin, you have to check for all the conditions according to your scenario and then only the records matching with your criteria will be processed through batch.